# React props not working for me I am designing a card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am learning React.js these days..i was designing a card by react...you can view my code below...please explain where i am missing.... Output is not showing any image and only showing one card output not all cards.....

Card Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Card(props){
    return(
        <>
    <div className="main">
        <div className="img1">
            <img src={props.imgsrc} alt="card image"/>
            <div className="title">
                <h3>{props.title}</h3>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat, repellat.</p>
                <button>watch now</button>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <>
    <Card  imgsrc="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" title="First Image"/>
    <Card imgsrc="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" title="Second Image"/>
    <Card imgsrc="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp6672547.jpg" title="Third Image"/>
    </>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

export default Card;
```

App Component:

```
import Card from "./Card"
// other imports

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Heading />
            <Imgs />
            <Tme />
            <Calc />
            <hr></hr>
            <Card />
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: How do you import card?

Comment: Thanks Sir for reply.... I'm importing like this...import Card from './Card';

Comment: function App(){
return(
  <>
  
    <Heading/>
    <Imgs/>
   <Tme />
    <Calc />
    <hr></hr>
    <Card />
</>
);

Comment: @awaisbtu you should edit your question and add this information. It is essential to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Card` component actually works as a standalone react app. This is because when you run the entire script it also executes the `ReactDOM.render` function which renders your react element at `#root` and on that situation, no React Element has been rendered yet prior to calling `ReactDOM.render`.

```js
function Card(props){
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="main">
              <div className="img1">
                <img src={props.imgsrc} alt="card image"/>
                <div className="title">
                    <h3>{props.title}</h3>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat, repellat.</p>
                    <button>watch now</button>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Card  imgsrc="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" title="First Image"/>
      <Card imgsrc="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" title="Second Image"/>
      <Card imgsrc="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp6672547.jpg" title="Third Image"/>
    </React.Fragment>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

It does not work when you are importing `Card` to the `App` because a React Element has probably already been rendered there (e.g., the parent component `App`), therefore calling `ReactDOM.render` again on the same html element `#root` will cause unexpected results.

So to solve the issue with regards to only 1 card is rendering & the images are not showing, just simply copy what you've done on inside the `ReactDOM.render` to what the `App` is returning

```
// essential imports here

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Heading />
            <Imgs />
            <Tme />
            <Calc />
            <hr>
            </hr>
            <Card imgsrc="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" title="First Image" />
            <Card imgsrc="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" title="Second Image" />
            <Card imgsrc="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp6672547.jpg" title="Third Image" />
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir.....i got it....Appreciated Bro....now i got my answer and solution as well....

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited your question to include the essential code about the `App` component. Please refrain from tagging as "solved" in your question title - the accepted answer should suffice. Welcome to Stack Overflow!!

Answer (score 0):

Follow : `npx create-react-app project-name`

When you open the project directory you will find :
**modules folder, public folder, src folder, package-lock.json, package.json**
In the src folder , create a folder named **components** where it gather all your components like **Card** component
*Card.js*

```
import React from 'react';
function Card(props){
    return(
          <div className="main">
               <div className="img1"> 
                  <img src={props.imgsrc} alt="card image"/> 
                  <div className="title">
                      <h3>{props.title}</h3>
                      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat, repellat.</p>
                     <button>watch now</button>
                 </div> 
              </div> 
           </div>
) }
export default Card;
```

In *App.js* , this the right way to import Card to the root of the App

```
import Card from './components/Card';

function App(){
       return (
            <>
               <Card imgsrc=''your image" />
            </>
)}
```

Your code needs to separate the components.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not React expert, but I think you should Create your class extending React.Component, also I think you must call your props in the return card with this. One important stuff is in React should be just one parent use  (your code)  instead of <> </>. I will let the code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Cards extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props) }

    render() {
    return(
    <div className="main">
        <div className="img1">
            <img src={this.props.imgsrc} alt="card image"/>
            <div className="title">
                <h3>{this.props.title}</h3>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat, repellat.</p>
                <button>watch now</button>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
    <Card  imgsrc="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" title="First Image"/>
    <Card imgsrc="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" title="Second Image"/>
    <Card imgsrc="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp6672547.jpg" title="Third Image"/>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I hope it could help you, I'm learning react too, I am not an expert as I said before, Good luck!

Comment: You don't need to use classes in react. You can, although you don't need to. Unfortunately, I don't see how this could be a useful answer. Read up on stateless components. As well, They add hooks to react.

Comment: As I said before, I am learning React too, I am not expert in front-end, my specialty is at the back-end. I'm learning React and when I got some knowledge I'll learn hor hooks works and redux too.

Comment: I understand,  I don't want to be mean or anything but your answer is just wrong and not helpful. Someone already down voted it. I just suggest that you remove it for now. Till you get better acquaint with react.